# Vertical alignment on an html input tag of type color

Tags: html, css

I have two inputs with a height set on them.  The second one is of type color.

Does anyone know why the color one is higher up than the text one?

```css
input {
  height: 40px; 
}
```

```html
<input /><input type='color' />
```

PS - I'm testing it in firefox and chrome desktop browsers.

I know I can fix it with a vertical alignment.  I am just curious to why I have to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the effect of rendering inline elements along the baseline of a a line box (as in CSS box model).

It appears that the browser is rendering `input` with `type=color` the same way it renders an inline image.

In my example, I added a small image inline with the `input` elements.

Note that the bottom edge of the `input` of `type=color` element lines up with the baseline of the text in the `input` element to the right, similarly to the bottom edge of the image.  For the input color element, the baseline appears to be defined along the bottom edge of the color panel.

There is a slight discrepancy between the color input and the image due to how the browser chooses to render the color input (default margin and or padding).

As you noted, using `vertical-align` will allow you to control the placement along the baseline.

```css
input {
  height: 40px;
}
input, img {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<input value="text for showing baseline" /><input type='color' /><img src="http://placehold.it/100x40">
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and thanks Marc.  Your excellent example shows exactly why it is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Because [**input**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) is inline element you can use [**vertical-align: middle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

```css
input {
  height: 40px;
}
input[type='color'] {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<input />
<input type='color' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been asked before. The text field has a default top margin of `10px`. However , `margin: 0px;` doesn't work for some reason. You can also observe this by moving the text field `10px` up.

```css
input {
  height: 40px; 
}
#text{
  position:relative;
  top: -10px;
  
  }
```

```html
<input id="text" /><input type='color' />
```